# Updating an atom with update and inc fails

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have an atom (in ClojureScript):

```
(def player
  (atom {:episode 0 ...}))
```

And I want to increment `:episode` by one:

```
(swap! player update :episode inc)
```

This works perfectly fine in Lein REPL.

However, when run, it throws:

```
mfp.js:5808 Uncaught Error: No protocol method IDeref.-deref defined for type cljs.core/PersistentHashMap: ...

    at Object.cljs$core$missing_protocol [as missing_protocol] (mfp.js:5808)
    at Object.cljs$core$_deref [as _deref] (mfp.js:7268)
    at cljs$core$deref (mfp.js:9396)
    at mfp$update (mfp.js:36808)
    at mfp.js:18388
    at Function.cljs.core.swap_BANG_.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$4 (mfp.js:18389)
    at cljs$core$swap_BANG_ (mfp.js:18341)
    at mfp$next_episode (mfp.js:36946)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (mfp.js:36920)
```

I can workaround this by using a longer form:

```
(swap! player assoc :episode (+ 1 (@player :episode)))
```

However, I would like to know why the first form does not work. Thank you.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to `swap!` a dereferenced value instead of an atom itself. Make sure you are passing an atom to `swap!`.

Comment: What is the code that doesn't work? `(swap! player update :episode inc)` should work as you say.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I agree broadly, but are you sure this is the error message you'd get if `player` were a map? To someone like me more used to JVM-clojure, it looks like an atom containing a hashmap, but the function being passed isn't `inc` - it's some function that tries to deref its input. In fact I see cljs.core/update is calling deref directly - it's almost as if someone wrote `(swap! player update :k deref)`

Comment: @amalloy You're right. The first line of the error seemed straight forward and common enough that I glazed over the rest. That would be an even stranger mistake to make though.

Comment: And actually, I'm wrong about the second not working as well. The "implicit function" that `swap!` allows was throwing me for some reason. I think switching to C is rotting my brain.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that update is redefined in OP's namespace. I see mps$update on the stack, not cljs$core$update.

Comment: @ez121sl I think you're right. I didn't notice it because I am not used to how cljs minifies its sources. Do the line numbers have a hint? `update` is defined very shortly after `next-episode`.

Comment: @ez121sl You're absolutely right! `update` was redefined which I didn't notice. Such a stupid mistake. Thank you all for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ez121sl pointed out in the comments, function `update` is redefined somewhere else in the code, which caused an error.

Answer (score 0):

What versions of Clojure/ClojureScript are you using? I just give the following a try:

**project.clj**

```
(defproject cljsdemo "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "EPL-2.0 OR GPL-2.0-or-later WITH Classpath-exception-2.0"
            :url "https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.10.520"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot cljsdemo.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}}
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.7"]]
  :cljsbuild {
              :builds [{
                        ;; The path to the top-level ClojureScript source directory:
                        :source-paths ["src-cljs"]
                        ;; The standard ClojureScript compiler options:
                        ;; (See the ClojureScript compiler documentation for details.)
                        :compiler {:output-to "public/js/main.js" ;; default: target/cljsbuild-main.js
                                   :optimizations :advanced
                                   :pretty-print false}}]}
```

**src-cljs/foo/demo.cljs**

```
(ns foo.demo)

(def player
  (atom {:episode 0 :hello "world"}))

(println
 (clj->js
  (swap! player update :episode inc)))
```

**public/index.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Testing...</h1>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The directory structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── project.clj
├── public
│   └── index.html
└── src-cljs
    └── foo
        └── demo.cljs
```

To compile the code: `lein cljsbuild once`.

Then I start a web server with: `cd public; python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3000` and open http://0.0.0.0:3000/ on Firefox, I see the following on the JavaScript console:

```
#js {:episode 1, :hello world}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As @ez121sl pointed in the comments, `update` was redefined in the code which caused the problem.

Comment: @Siegmeyer Comments are ephemeral, and should be treated as if they could disappear anytime. If you've found an answer to your question, please record this fact by posting it as an answer.

Comment: Sure thing, will do.